# Converting Reference style

Tags: bibliographies

I have a prepared a document with IEEE reference style using IEEE journal template. I want to change the reference style to author-year style e.g. [Jones,A.D 2006] than numeric style like [1]. How can I do that with least change to the tex document.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
%[]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing} 


\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]

\end{abstract}


\section{INTRODUCTION}
\lipsum[1-2]\cite{FCC}, \cite{Akyildiz_06}\\
 .\lipsum[1] \cite{Goldsmith_05}. \\


\begin{thebibliography}{40}

  \bibitem{FCC} FCC, “Spectrum Policy Task Force Report,” Report of the Spectrum Efficiency Working Group, Nov. 2002.

  \bibitem{Akyildiz_06}Akyildiz, Ian F., et al. "NeXt generation/dynamic spectrum access/cognitive radio wireless networks: a survey." \emph{Computer Networks} 50.13 (2006): 2127-2159.

  \bibitem{Goldsmith_05}Goldsmith, Andrea. \emph{Wireless communications.} Cambridge university press, 2005.

  \bibitem{OFDM_arslan}  Mahmoud, H., Tevfik Yucek, and Hüseyin Arslan. “OFDM for cognitive radio: merits and challenges." \emph{Wireless Communications, IEEE} 16.2 (2009): 6-15.

  \bibitem{Cor_OFDM06} Char-Dir Chung, "Correlatively coded OFDM," \emph{Wireless Communications, IEEE Transactions on} , vol.5, no.8, pp.2044,2049, Aug. 2006

  \bibitem{Jondral04} T. Weiss, J. Hillenbrand, A. Krohn, and F. Jondral, “Mutual interference in OFDM-based spectrum pooling systems,”\emph{ in Proc. IEEE Vehic. Technol. Conf. (VTC)}, vol. 4, May 2004, pp. 1873–1877.


  \bibitem{CR_mod}Budiarjo, I.; Nikookar, H.; Ligthart, L.P., "Cognitive radio modulation techniques," \emph{Signal Processing Magazine, IEEE} , vol.25, no.6, pp.24,34, November 2008.



\end{thebibliography}





\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a MWE that I can use for my answer?

Comment: I am new to LaTex. What do you mean by MWE?

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that . A code that I can copy paste withe the modification that I made and that you can easily test

Comment: Are you creating the bibliography entirely by hand, or are you using a tool such as BibTeX?

Comment: I have created the bibliography entirely by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I've reduced your bibliography :

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
%[]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{Orthogonal Frequency Division Multiplexing} 

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]

\end{abstract}


\section{INTRODUCTION}
\lipsum[1-2]\cite{FCC}, \cite{Akyildiz_06}\\
 .\lipsum[1] \cite{Goldsmith_05}. \\


\begin{thebibliography}{40}

  \bibitem[FCC, 2002]{FCC} FCC, “Spectrum Policy Task Force Report,” Report of the Spectrum Efficiency Working Group, Nov. 2002.

  \bibitem[Akyildiz, I. 2006]{Akyildiz_06}Akyildiz, Ian F., et al. "NeXt generation/dynamic spectrum access/cognitive radio wireless networks: a survey." \emph{Computer Networks} 50.13 (2006): 2127-2159.

  \bibitem[Goldsmith, A. 2006]{Goldsmith_05}Goldsmith, Andrea. \emph{Wireless communications.} Cambridge university press, 2005.

  \bibitem[Mahmoud, H. 2009]{OFDM_arslan}  Mahmoud, H., Tevfik Yucek, and Hüseyin Arslan. “OFDM for cognitive radio: merits and challenges." \emph{Wireless Communications, IEEE} 16.2 (2009): 6-15.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

When writing a `\bibitem`, the value between the `[]` indicate what will be the label in the text.